# Hide compasses on Android/apple map by Titanium map module

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, titanium, apple-maps

I am using titanium map Module to show Google/apple map

There is the compass on each Google/Apple map on the right-upper side.

For now, I put another button to hide the compass button.

However, there is a way to hide the compass??
Or make another compass button somewhere else in the screen?

Answer (score 0):

compassEnabled : Boolean

Enable or disables the compass button.

Default: true
Version-3.2.3

Because the default value comes out to be true you would always get a compass on the map by default.Set the value of compassEnabled to false.
compassEnabled(false)

Comment: Thanks , it seems valid on Android , not iOS. Thanks anyway.